# SQL Divide previous row balance by current row balance and insert that value into current rows column "Growth"

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where like this.

| Year | ProcessDate | Month | Balance | RowNum | Calculation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | 20220430 | 4 | 22855547 | 1 |  |
| 2022 | 20220330 | 3 | 22644455 | 2 |  |
| 2022 | 20220230 | 2 | 22588666 | 3 |  |
| 2022 | 20220130 | 1 | 33545444 | 4 |  |
| 2022 | 20221230 | 12 | 22466666 | 5 |  |

I need to take the previous row of each column and divide that amount by the current row.

Ex: Row 1 calculation should = Row 2 Balance / Row 1 Balance (22644455/22855547 = .99% )
Row 2 calculation should = Row 3 Balance / Row 2 Balance etc....

Table is just a Temporary table I created titled #MonthlyLoanBalance2.
Now I just need to take it a step further.
Let me know what and how you would go about doing this.
Thank you in advance!

```
Insert into #MonthlytLoanBalance2 (
Year
,ProcessDate
,Month
,Balance
,RowNum
)
select 
--CloseYearMonth,
left(ProcessDate,4) as 'Year',
ProcessDate,
--x.LOANTypeKey,
SUBSTRING(CAST(x.ProcessDate as varchar(38)),5,2) as 'Month',
sum(x.currentBalance) as Balance
,ROW_NUMBER()over (order by ProcessDate desc) as RowNum
from
(
select 
distinct LoanServiceKey,
LoanTypeKey,
AccountNumber,
CurrentBalance,
OpenDateKey,
CloseDateKey,
ProcessDate


from
cu.LAFactLoanSnapShot
where LoanStatus = 'Open'
and LoanTypeKey = 0
and ProcessDate in (select DateKey from dimDate
where IsLastDayOfMonth = 'Y'
and DateKey > convert(varchar, getdate()-4000, 112)

)

) x

group by ProcessDate
order by ProcessDate desc;``
```

Comment: This looks like SQL server so I'll tag it so.

Comment: First: never use varchar without a size because the default is 1 and it silently truncates. change this `convert(varchar, getdate()` to this `convert(varchar(50), getdate()`

Comment: And `SUBSTRING(CAST(x.ProcessDate as varchar(38)),5,2) as 'Month'`? Wy not just `DATEPART(MONTH, ...)`? Also `getdate()-4000`? Subtracting about 11 years? Use `DATEADD(DAY, ...)` and be explicit.

Comment: you can use Lead() function to achieve your goal

Comment: @AaronBertrand Agreed. I'm throwing stuff together quickly before I actually set dates and what not. 
I will look into DatePart. I have not used that before.

Comment: Sure, `SELECT DATEPART(MONTH, '20220510');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming your data is already prepared as shown in the table. Now you can try **Lead()** function to resolve your issue. Remember format() function is used for taking only two precision.

```
SELECT *,
    FORMAT((ISNULL(LEAD(Balance,1) OVER (ORDER BY RowNum), 1)/Balance),'N2') Calculation
FROM #MonthlytLoanBalance2
```

Comment: This looks like what I need! Can this put a minus sign in front of the number when it is in the negative direction? I want to see clearly if it is a decrease or an increase

Comment: Obviously, it can. You can also check the negative direction with this query.

Comment: I adjusted it and found a way to get things calculated. Thank you!!